# c# Linq expression builder Expression.Equal showing parms around the wrong way

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to build some dynamic Linq using expressions for an advance search facility.

I call my define expression builder like so:

```
IQueryable<DocPod> retval = Enumerable.Empty<Doc>().AsQueryable();
retval = DefineSearchExpression(x => x.Id,                  
                                     searchCriteria.searchData.Comparison,
                                     searchCriteria.searchData.NumberFrom,                                            
                                     searchCriteria.searchData.NumberTo);
```

To explain the above, I have multiple properties on a page where each property  has a drop down providing various search types, so in the case above I have an int called Id, then a comparison which can be things like equals, not equals, greater than, etc... Then depending on the selected comparison, NumberFrom is the main search parameter and should always be populated, but in the case of between comparison, the NumberTo parameter is also populated.

The function DefineSearchExpression, is shown below:

```
    private IQueryable<Docs> DefineSearchExpression(Expression<Func<Docs, object>> searchColumnName, int compare, object minValue, object maxValue)
    {
        IQueryable<Docs> retval = Entities.Docs.AsQueryable();

        // We must have a minValue to process
        if (minValue == null)
        {
            return retval;
        }

        // LINQ Expression that represents the column passed in searchColumn
        var columnExpression = GetMemberExpression(searchColumnName);

        // LINQ Expression to represent the parameter of the lambda you pass in
        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = (ParameterExpression)columnExpression.Expression;
        // Expressions to represent min and max values
        Expression minValueExpression = null;
        Expression maxValueExpression = null;
        Expression minComparisonExpression = null;
        Expression maxComparisonExpression = null;

         // Represents the completed filter
        Expression<Func<Docs, bool>> filterLambdaExpression = null; 
        // setup vars
        if (minValue.IsNumeric())
        {
            var intfromValue = int.Parse(minValue.ToString());
            minValueExpression = Expression.Constant(intfromValue);
            if (maxValue != null)
            {
                var inttoValue = int.Parse(maxValue.ToString());
                maxValueExpression = Expression.Constant(inttoValue);
            }
        }
        else if (minValue.IsDate())
        {
            var dtfromValue = DateTime.Parse(minValue.ToString());
            minValueExpression = Expression.Constant(dtfromValue);
            if (maxValue != null)
            {

                var dttoValue = DateTime.Parse(maxValue.ToString());
                maxValueExpression = Expression.Constant(dttoValue);
            }
        }

        // Expression represented by selection in dropdown List
        switch (compare)
        {
            //
            // THIS IS WHERE THE FIRST ISSUES IS LOCATED
            //
            //
            case 0: // This should be equivalent to: field = value
                minComparisonExpression = Expression.Equal(minValueExpression, columnExpression);
                filterLambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Docs, bool>>(minComparisonExpression, parameterExpression);
                break;
        }

        retval = retval.AsQueryable().Where(filterLambdaExpression);
        return retval.AsQueryable();
    }
```

As you can see, I am trying to take into account numeric, datetime and finally string data for searching.

When the above code is executed, when the code within the switch Case 0 provides the following anomaly.

minComparisonExpression has the debug value of 1977836648 == $x.Id

I have tried to swap these values around, but with little success, if anyone knows how to fix this, I would be very grateful.

Secondly, when DefineSearchExpression returns, the new expression is lost, this is most probably me, but I just cannot see it.

Oops. Thank you for spotting the error, but that does not help as the offending code is in the Switch Case 0 statements, the date code is not run at all at the moment.

Code updated!

Comment: You have a typo in the date you use `minComparisonExpression` instead of `minValueExpression`

Comment: Ofir, where do you mean?

Comment: The first argument to `Expression.Equal` (and `BinaryExpression` in general) is `left`, the second is `right`. So you really need to swap the arguments.

Comment: I did that, to start off minComparisonExpression = Expression.Equal(minValueExpression, columnExpression); actually read minComparisonExpression = Expression.Equal(columnExpression, minValueExpression);

Comment: What's the value of `intfromValue` after the parsing?

Comment: It is an numeric value of type int

Comment: @gilesrpa i mean in the specific case when it gives you `1977836648`